# v.out.ogr to PGDUMP using COPY

Tags: grass-gis, grass-7.4

I am exporting a grass vectior dataset to a Postgis dump file using v.out.ogr (reformatted for clarity)

```
v.out.ogr -a -n input=my_layer@mapset\
                output=my_sql_file.sql format=PGDUMP
```

It exports using insert statements by default, but the ogr2ogr docs suggest that using a switch enables COPY format instead (--config PG_USE_COPY YES).  COPY is much faster and is also easier to debug when errors occur.

I tried using PG_USE_COPY=YES as both a dsco and lco option, and exporting it (ubuntu 18.04 command line in grass environment).

```
export PG_USE_COPY=YES
```

Is it possible to export using COPY format?

What am I doing wrong?

[edit]

My problem was caused by creating a layer by merging server datasets, one of which had an ogc_fid field (default primary key for ogr2ogr).  This caused loading to fail after several thousand insert statements.  I solved it by editing the sql file to rename the primary key and add ogc_fid as an integer field.

Comment: Maybe use the direct PostGIS connector: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/PostGIS#Direct_write_access

Comment: @markusN Thanks, will try that when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to markusN for an answer in a comment.

It looks like it is not possible to export to PGDUMP using COPY rather than INSERT at present.

Direct write access https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/PostGIS#Direct_write_access appears like a promising approach but I have not tried it.

https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/v.out.postgis.html has worked for me, as has manually editing the sql file to convert to copy format (using sed).